# How to play music from list view

Tags: android, listview, internet-radio

I am developing an android application , It is an online radio in which I can play music with the streaming urls. I want to list all the urls with titles in a list view in one class and on clicking each item I want to play the corresponding stations with the url.Can anybody give some suggestions on how to establish this concept ? Currently I have my streaming is working with a single url .But it is not in the listview.

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: Currently I can play stream with single url , I want to play from a playlist , in list I have several urls , How could I achieve it..?

Comment: By starting playback of the url that the user selects by clicking on it..? Your problem description is still quite vague. If you don't know how to incorporate a ListView in your app, search for some tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

Just devlop listview and depends on item click start a asynctask or any background task with your logic to play music...